# How to generate true randomness in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There is the `Math.random()` function in JavaScript. But this is not the answer, because I want to know how to generate a random number without this function, just pure randomness.

Comment: True randomness doesn't exist, even outside of programming (IMO)

Comment: check out https://www.random.org/, maybe they have an API. or somebody else might have created a 3rd-party API for it. then you could make async calls to this API to get a random number.

Comment: I get it, it does not exist. But try to at least think about it. And not immediately suggest other answers or API’s. Because that does not answer my question

Comment: @CertainPerformance - in quantum physics it does

Comment: Please see this [language proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-seeded-random)

Comment: Looking for a [random.org](https://random.org) API is a good suggestion. Comments don't need to answer the question. They generate their randomness using real world data like cameras pointed at lava lamps so they can achieve higher levels of entropy, which is presumably what you mean by "true randomness"

Comment: check out [ https://github.com/lordpoint/xorshift-sandbox-and-visualizer ]